# How to reset mysql pointer back to the first row in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo $row['id'];}
```

If I use the above code two times consecutively, the row does not get printed twice.

How to reset it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use [mysql_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php). This function will allow you to move the internal result pointer.