# How do I reset a PHP pointer for a MySQL resource?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset mysql pointer back to the first row in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817997/how-to-reset-mysql-pointer-back-to-the-first-row-in-php)

I have 2 while loops in my PHP script that processes a list of data from a database.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($results))  {
    // do stuff
}

reset($results);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($results))  {
    // do some more stuff
}
```

However, the reset() function is not resetting my pointer within the MySQL resource. In fact, it generates an error:

> "Warning: reset() [function.reset]: Passed variable is not an array or
>   object in  /home/cs179_team13/public_html/timeTests/results.php on
>   line 133."

Why? How do I reset a PHP pointer for a MySQL resource?

Comment: You can't reset a `resource` type - it isn't an array. Just do the query again.

Comment: Thank you. However, can I somehow avoid doing the query again? I don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: `mysql_data_seek($results, 0);`

Comment: _I don't want to repeat myself_ - you can put the query into a string and use it twice, surely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function `mysql_data_seek`.

`bool mysql_data_seek ( resource $result , int $row_number )`

More information can be a found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php.

Comment: This answer is correct but outdated. From the manual: deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use instead: $result->data_seek(0);

Answer (score 3):

You don't need such an ugly way.
Just get yourself an array.

```
$data = sql_to_arr("SELECT * FROM myTable");
foreach ($data as $row)  {
    // do stuff
}
foreach ($data as $row)  {
    // do stuff
}
foreach ($data as $row)  {
    // do stuff
}
```

this is way more convenient way to deal with data

Answer (score 3):

Pass the resultset returned along with 0

```
mysql_data_seek($resultset, 0) ;//reset result set
```