# How to reuse the resulted variable after executing a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing a query like this (PHP + MySQL):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // PHP Statement 
}
```

I want to use the same result again on the same page then i need to execute query again like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // PHP Code 
}
```

then it works. But if I use only

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // PHP Code
}
```

Then it doesn't work. Is there any other way to use the result many times on the same page without executing query every time?

I know i can use the same result to make an array. but is there any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset mysql pointer back to the first row in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817997/how-to-reset-mysql-pointer-back-to-the-first-row-in-php)

Comment: For a start the `mysql_` library is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [mysql_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) will do this for you.

```
<?php
function mysql_pointer_position($result_set) {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_set);
        $i = 0;
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
            $i++;
        }
        $pointer_position = $num_rows - $i;

//Return pointer to original position
        if($pointer_position <= $num_rows - 1) {
            mysql_data_seek($result_set, $pointer_position);
        }
        return $pointer_position;
    }
?>
```