# while loops inside an email (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, email, shopping-cart

I am trying to email the details from a shopping cart upon completion of payment. I have a confirmation page which successfully displays this information but when trying to email I cant get the item details to pass through.

I wasnt sure if it was something to do with the while loop inside the email code.

the sample of my email message holding the items information is:

```
$email_message .= "<p class='regular'>Your ordered:</p>
                                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                            <table class='orderTable'>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class='prodNumber'>Product Description</th>
                                                    <th class='qty'>Qty</th>
                                                    <th class='subTotal'>Sub Total</th>
                                                </tr>";
                                                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($orderDetailInfo)){
                        $email_message .= "     <tr>
                                                        <td class='prodNumber'>".$row3['productID']."</td>
                                                        <td class='qty'>".$row3['quantity']."</td>
                                                        <td class='subTotal'>".$row3['total']."</td>

                                                    </tr>";
                                                }
                        $email_message .= " <tr>
                                                    <th class='prodNumber'>Delivery</th>
                                                    <th class='qty'>Tax</th>
                                                    <th class='subTotal'>Total Amount</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='prodNumber'>".$row['delivery']."</td>
                                                    <td class='qty'>".$row['salesTax']."</td>
                                                    <td class='subTotal'>".$row['totalPrice']."</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
```

the SQL is used above this code to retrieve the data for the confirmation page. I am just trying to re-loop through it again to populate the email. the Email does send with all other pieces of content just not the product data. can someone see anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: What output you get by `echo $email_message;` after all operation you perform on it ?

Comment: Well the email sends with all the content in it apart from the item details which are fetched from the database with the while loop...however the exact same process is used on the confirmation page and it works perfectly there

Comment: What is `$orderDetailInfo`?

Comment: Seems you're closing your while loop very earlier.

Comment: @Explosion Pills that is the query i use to retrieve the data

Comment: @Kevlar okay but I want to know what it *is* -- show the code that creates it

Comment: @Explosion Pills $orderDetailInfo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE orderNumber = '$orderID'");

Comment: I would suggest you to print the SQL instead of running it and then use that to run directly in the database and see if you get any results. Unfortunately don't quite remember how to use the mysqli functions to interact with the database but there might be a step missing somewhere that then prevents you from getting anything in $orderDetailInfo.

Comment: the SQL is used above this code to retrieve the data for the confirmation page. I am just trying to re-loop through it again to populate the email. the Email does send with all other pieces of content..just not the product data

Comment: @Kevlar and you're sure that works?

Comment: Check is code getting inside your while loop ?

Comment: @Explosion Pills yeah its already been used above this code in the same file to populate the page before the email generates. Rikesh, how do i check this?

Comment: Just print a different <td> with some static text. It could help to provide the full page code in a pastebin or something, because it seems fine from here.

Comment: Also, do you by any chance do a mysqli_free_result($orderDetailInfo); before trying to use it again?

Comment: @Leite no i dont do a mysqli_free_result. but I have just added it. I have added another <td> with some static text in the while loop and that does not appear either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are re-looping the `$orderDetailInfo` you need to reset it's pointer. By reading your post, you've looped it once already so you are at the end of the result set, check [How to reset mysql pointer back to the first row in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817997/how-to-reset-mysql-pointer-back-to-the-first-row-in-php).

In your case it would be [mysqli_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Basically, before your `while` do `$orderDetailInfo->data_seek(0);` or if that fails, this `mysqli_data_seek($orderDetailInfo, 0);`.

Comment: I have renamed it the second time i use it from $row2 to $row3

Comment: That doesn't matter, your resultset is at the end of the results, so there are no more to fetch, you need to make it return to the 1st result so you can use it again.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both options but neither make any difference :( so the beginning of my while loop now looks like this mysqli_data_seek($orderDetailInfo, 0); 
             while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($orderDetailInfo)){

Comment: sorry, it did work. I just left the mysqli_free_result line in as well and that was stopping the mysqli_data_seek. Thanks for leading me to this solution :) i appreciate it

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't do the `mysqli_free_result`, I've asked in a comment above because if you did you would just be clearing your resultset and wouldn't be able to use it again. Anyway, glad you reached a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're while loop is clearing the $row variable. Rename the $row in the while loop.

Comment: Can you show me the output for `$email_message` and can you check if you put `$email_message` in your mail body?

Comment: Thankyou for your online purchase, your order has been sent to a member of our sales team to be processed. Your Order Number is: 10050

Your ordered:

 

Product Description Qty Sub Total 
Delivery Tax Total Amount 
50.00 14.08 134.48

Comment: try adding:
    if (!$orderDetailInfo){
        echo 'Error:' . mysqli_error($con);
    }

Maybe the query is wrong?

Comment: the query is used above this code in the same file to populate the confirmation page.

Comment: My bad.. check @Leite 's link ->  mysqli_data_seek($orderDetailInfo, 0)