# php nested while loops not going through all options

Tags: php

I have been trying to get this to loop though each option for multiple rows. If I take out the continue it will not loop through the multiple rows if I have it in the second while loop is not ran.

I have tried placing the continue before the end of the second while loop and at the end of the first while loop. I have also tried taking the second while loop out i have tried using a foreach where the second while loop is, I am at a lost of why this is not working. I have also nested the while loops and still did not get what I wanted

```
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." name="."ponumber".">" . $rs['CompanyName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." name="."total".">" . $rs['PONo'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." name="."state".">" . $rs['PODate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." name="."zip".">" . $rs['Total'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." >

      <input type='checkbox' >
      </td>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." >
      <select>";
    }

while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $sql="select distinct DFTerms from company where DFTerms is not null";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<option value=".$rs['DFTerms'].">".$rs['DFTerms']."</option>";
      }
      echo "   </select>
      </td>";
      echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>
 ";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I expect to get the types of accounts in the drop down and I get nothing. if I do it any other way there is either no drop down if if there is a second PO number for the same vendor it is not shown

This is what I get
[image]

This is what I need but for both PO's
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this pair of loops, you are using `$result` in both parts, overwriting the previous result set...

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

SO just change the inner variable name (or come up with a more meaningful name)...

```
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $sql="select distinct DFTerms from company where DFTerms is not null";
      $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo "<option value=".$rs['DFTerms'].">".$rs['DFTerms']."</option>";
      }
      echo "   </select>
      </td>";
      echo "</tr>";
}
```

Also your first and second loop in the code you show use the same result set, if this is what is intended, you would need to either re-execute the SQL or position the result set at the beginning again - [How to reset mysql pointer back to the first row in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817997/how-to-reset-mysql-pointer-back-to-the-first-row-in-php).

Comment: Thank you I am so use to just using the same result set over and over again I didn't think of that.